# Iterate through rows, compare them against each other and store results in another table

Tags: postgresql, iteration

I have a table that contains the following rows:

```
product_id | order_date
A          | 12/04/12
A          | 01/11/13
A          | 01/21/13
A          | 03/05/13
B          | 02/14/13
B          | 03/09/13
```

What I now need is an overview for each month, how many products have been bought for the first time (=have not been bought the month before), how many are existing products (=have been bought the month before) and how many have not been purchased within a given month. Taken the sample above as an input, the script should deliver the following result, regardless of what period of time is in the data:

```
month   | new | existing | nopurchase
12/2012 | 1   | 0        | 0
01/2013 | 0   | 1        | 0
02/2013 | 1   | 0        | 1
03/2013 | 1   | 1        | 0
```

Would be great to get a first hint how this could be solved so I'm able to continue.

Thanks!

Comment: As this is a postgresql specific question, do you want the pseudo code  or the postgresql specific function?

Comment: Both would be helpful, but the postgres function would be my primary interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5ef84/3)

```
with t as (
    select product_id pid, date_trunc('month', order_date)::date od
    from t
    group by 1, 2
)
select od,
    sum(is_new::integer) "new",
    sum(is_existing::integer) existing,
    sum(not_purchased::integer) nopurchase
from (
    select od,
        lag(t_pid) over(partition by s_pid order by od) is null and t_pid is not null is_new,
        lag(t_pid) over(partition by s_pid order by od) is not null and t_pid is not null is_existing,
        lag(t_pid) over(partition by s_pid order by od) is not null and t_pid is null not_purchased
    from (
        select t.pid t_pid, s.pid s_pid, s.od
        from
            t
            right join
            (
                select pid, s.od
                from
                    t
                    cross join
                    (
                        select date_trunc('month', d)::date od
                        from
                        generate_series(
                            (select min(od) from t),
                            (select max(od) from t),
                            '1 month'
                        ) s(d)
                    ) s 
                group by pid, s.od
            ) s on t.od = s.od and t.pid = s.pid
    ) s
) s
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Well, nothing less than perfect. Thanks!